# XOR gate with 4 inputs - truth table & MDNF?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have difficulties with one equation. It's an XOR gate with 4 inputs.

> F(A,B,C,D)=(A⊕B)*C+(B⊕C)*(A⊕C)

'B' from the second bracket has a line above it , so does the 'A' from the third. 
I did the truth table,but once transferred to Karnaugh map, the result is very hard to work with:

> ```
> 0 1 0 1
> 1 0 1 0
> 0 1 0 1
> 1 0 1 0
> ```

Using it, it's very hard to find the minimal disjunctive normal form,since I can't combine any of the TRUE's . I'm not sure if doing each one seperately is the correct way to do it ,since we haven't studied that yet in uni.How to proceed?

Truth table:

```
 a b c d | XOR | OP |
|---------+-----+----|
| 0 0 0 0 |   0 | 0  |
| 0 0 0 1 |   1 | 1  |
| 0 0 1 0 |   1 | 1  |
| 0 0 1 1 |   0 | 0  |
| 0 1 0 0 |   1 | 1  |
| 0 1 0 1 |   0 | 0  |
| 0 1 1 0 |   0 | 0  |
| 0 1 1 1 |   1 | 0  |
| 1 0 0 0 |   1 | 1  |
| 1 0 0 1 |   0 | 0  |
| 1 0 1 0 |   0 | 0  |
| 1 0 1 1 |   1 | 0  |
| 1 1 0 0 |   0 | 0  |
| 1 1 0 1 |   1 | 0  |
| 1 1 1 0 |   1 | 0  |
| 1 1 1 1 |   0 | 0  |
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I can immediately tell that your K-map is wrong, since there is no $D$ in the formula, so we should be able to group everything in groups of two or more.

Second, so your formula is $(A \oplus B)C + (\bar{B} \oplus C)(\bar{A} \oplus C)$

OK, so for the first term we get a 1 when C is true and exactly one of $A$ and $B$ is true.

For the second term we get a 1 when two things are true: $\bar{B} \oplus C$ (and that is true when B and C have the same value) and when $\bar{A} \oplus C$ is true ( and that is true when A and C have the same value). Together, this means that the second term is a 1 when A, B, and C all have the same value.

here is the K-map I get (blue is for first term, and red for second):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \bar{A} \bar{B} & A \bar{B} & AB & \bar{A}B\\
\hline
\bar{C} \bar{D} & \color{red}1 & 0&0&0\\
\hline
C \bar{D} & 0&\color{blue}1&\color{red}1&\color{blue}1\\
\hline
CD &0&\color{blue}1&\color{red}1&\color{blue}1\\
\hline
\bar{C}D &\color{red}1&0&0&0\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Yes, that's my formula. How would you do my K-map?

Comment: @Tisho Never tried a K-map in Mathjax before .... Let me try ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need this work done for tomorrow and I've ran out of ideas and knowledge myself.

Comment: @Tisho Ok, it's up! You know how to group, right?

Comment: Would you mind a short explation as to why that is the correct K-map?  After all ,i'd like to understand, not just copy you. :) And aren't usually A and B inputs vertical, while C and D - horizontal in the K-map? 
I believe i do ,yea. Maybe my truth table is wrong as well, do you include D in it?

Comment: Added truth table to main post.

Comment: @Tisho what is the XOR and OP in your truth table?  I did add explanation for my K-map.  And yes, I have A and B for the verticals, and C and D for the horizontals (not that it matters, really!)

Comment: XOR is what i have as logical value of the function aka what I type in the k-map at it's correct position.  THat's how we're teached to be done. With XOR gate, uneven number of 1's equals 1 as the result of the function.